# Why do ASC and DESC come *after* a CASE clause?

Tags: sql-server, syntax

This query works:

```
DECLARE @Ordering NVARCHAR(50)
SET @Ordering = 'aggregateid'

DECLARE @OrderDirectionInt INT
SET @OrderDirectionInt = 0 --1

SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY
            CASE WHEN LOWER(@Ordering) = 'aggregateid' AND @OrderDirectionInt = 1 THEN AggregateId END DESC,
            CASE WHEN LOWER(@Ordering) = 'aggregateid' AND @OrderDirectionInt = 0 THEN AggregateId END ASC
        ) AS RowNumber,
        MyField
    FROM
        MyTable
) AS TempResults
WHERE TempResults.RowNumber BETWEEN 12 AND 23
```

What I don't understand is why the `ASC` and `DESC` are *after* (or outside of) the `CASE` statements.  It looks like the `ASC` and `DESC` are being put in unconditionally, which doesn't make sense... it might resolve to:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY
    DESC,
    AggregateId ASC
) AS RowNumber
```

Why doesn't the `CASE` statement contain the `ASC` or `DESC` (if you try to do that you get a syntax error)?

Comment: Because a `CASE` expression (not clause) can have a value/expression as a result, not code words like `ASC` or `FROM`.

Comment: And don't forget that a `CASE` expression always returns a value; when the `ELSE` is omitted, it defaults to `ELSE NULL`.

Comment: So if none of the cases match, it's evaluating to "NULL DESC, NULL ASC"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Why do `ASC` and `DESC` come *after* a `CASE` clause?
- Why doesn't the `CASE` statement contain the `ASC` or `DESC` (if you try to do that you get a syntax error)?

Because a `CASE` **expression** (it's neither a clause nor a statement) can have a value/expression as a result, not code words like `ASC` or `FROM`. The syntax provided in [`CASE` expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms181765.aspx) documentation is:

```
Searched CASE expression:
CASE
     WHEN Boolean_expression 
       THEN result_expression [ ...n ] 
     [ ELSE else_result_expression ] 
END
```

- It might resolve to:

  ```
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY
      DESC,
      AggregateId ASC
  ) AS RowNumber
  ```

No, it cannot. Due to the implied `ELSE NULL` part that all `CASE` expressions have as a default, if you don't provide it.

Comment: Ah, so it really does resolve to `NULL DESC, AggregateId ASC`?  That does seem to work.  And presumably, SQL Server ignores "null order clauses" so it has no hit on performance?  Might be worth adding it to the answer.